# Display custom error pages with PHP 7 - details for me, generic for users

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling, php-7

Using Linux/Apache/PHP7, I want to display all error messages gracefully.  I have my .htaccess file with the following:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /errors/error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /errors/error.php
```

...which points to a error.php page with the following:

```
$status = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'];
$codes = array(
400 => array('400 Bad Request', 'The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.'),
403 => array('403 Forbidden', 'The server has refused to fulfil your request.'),
404 => array('404 Not Found', 'The page you requested was not found on this server.'),
405 => array('405 Method Not Allowed', 'The method specified in the request is not allowed for the specified resource.'),
408 => array('408 Request Timeout', 'Your browser failed to send a request in the time allowed by the server.'),
500 => array('500 Internal Server Error', 'The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.'),
502 => array('502 Bad Gateway', 'The server received an invalid response while trying to carry out the request.'),
504 => array('504 Gateway Timeout', 'The upstream server failed to send a request in the time allowed by the server.'),
);
$title = $codes[$status][0];
$message = $codes[$status][1];
if ($title == false || strlen($status) != 3) {
$message = 'Please supply a valid HTTP status code.';
}
echo '<h1>Hold up! '.$title.' detected</h1>
<p>'.$message.'</p>';
```

The 404 function seems to work just fine, but any php error like a typo in a function name still displays as a white screen with standard php error messages.  Even an intentional typo in the .htaccess file produces a generic 500 error, but doesn't use the error.php page I established for this purpose.

What I'd like to do also is display the php error details for me, but hide the details for users, even when in production mode.

Comment: This might sound bad, but "well duh" - you've told it how to handle HTTP errors (of which 404 is the easiest to test), but you haven't told it to do a thing with PHP errors. Look into `set_exception_handler` and `set_error_handler` (before PHP7), as well as `register_shutdown_function` to see if an error occurred there. All that being said, if there's an error in your error handler, all bets are off and you'll doubtless end up with exposed PHP errors.

Comment: Errors in `.htaccess` would make the `.htaccess`invalid and therefore not processed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I'll add it to help future readers. Errors in PHP-syntax aren't caught by Apache. As per [this thread on the webmasters forum](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115575/how-to-load-a-custom-error-page-on-php-syntax-error) there's some discussion on whether or not syntax errors are 'true' 500-errors. All of my browsers show it as a 500-code. But `ErrorDocument 500 /err500.php` is - just like your case - not triggered by it; it is however logged in the error-log you define in Apache. The fact that it logs, but doesn't trigger the `ErrorDocument` command is what got me and took me a while to figure out. I'm still looking for a workaround that doesn't require me to modify all PHP-pages on the page.